# Grafana: How to set Table cell color by comparing two values

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Using `Prometheus` as datasource, in `Grafana`, I have a `Table` visualization that lists kubernetes `containers` and their versions using this query:

```
kube_pod_container_info{namespace="$namespace", pod=~"pod-.*"}
```

Example table looks like this:

```
| pod          | Version |
| -------------| ------- |
| pod-firstapp | 123     |
| pod-secondapp| 456     |
```

This only lists *unique* versions of any given pod if there are multiple instances of it, so in case of a container being upgraded, or stuck during an upgrade, two rows for the same `pod` will appear, with different versions, like so:

```
| pod          | Version |
| -------------| ------- |
| pod-firstapp | 123     |
| pod-firstapp | 124     |
| pod-secondapp| 456     |
```

How could I highlight that 2nd row if and when it appears?
The only way I can think of is via `Value mappings` but I don't know if it's possible to set those to compare two values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it correct to assume you are not interested in actual count returned by `count_values` and they can be disregarded for goals of this task?

Comment: @markalex correct, the query can be simplified. I've edited the original post. The `count` was only added to remove the duplicate rows. Though I do suspect there's a better way of doing that.

Comment: FYI, your use of `count_values` was completely justified, and I don't think could be (at least easily) avoided. I was asking just for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare values of different columns in Table panel, but value mapping still can help you.

You can use query:

```
count by (container, image) (
 kube_pod_container_info{namespace="$namespace", pod=~"pod-.*"}
) * 0
+ on(container) group_left()
count by (container) (
 count by (container, image) (
  kube_pod_container_info{namespace="$namespace", pod=~"pod-.*"}
 )
)
```

After this you can add value mapping for column value, and replace 1 with `all actual`, and range 2-999 with something like `some are outdated` in red font.

Since version are stored in labels there is no way to find which one is outdated automatically, and you'll need to figure this yourself.

This wouldn't color whole row (AFAIK it is impossible for new version of Table panel), but I believe should be good enough for your cause.

---

If you want to be a bit more proactive, you can create alert with expression

```
count by (container) (
 count by (container, image) (
  kube_pod_container_info{namespace="$namespace", pod=~"pod-.*"}
 )
) > 1
```

It'll return containers that have more than 1 image version running on them.

Comment: This works exactly as I needed. Thanks a lot for your help @markalex!